# Find and copy data with a keyword from multiple workbooks into the master workbook

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to cycle through multiple .xls files and copy data that is located below the same keyword across multiple workbooks into the master workbook.

I managed to cycle through the files and copy the data using `Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`.

I struggle with the keyword part. It seems that I need to get the cell address and concatenate it with `lRow`, but I get a type mismatch error.

```vb
Sub looping_through999() 
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wbkMs As Object
    Dim lRow As Variant
    Dim lRow2 As Variant
    Set wbkMs = Workbooks("Filename.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheetname")
    Dim searchcell As Range 'new
    Dim offsetaddr As Range 'new
    strPath = "H:\folder_path\"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
       
    With wbkMs
        Do While strFile <> ""
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=strPath & "\" & strFile
                    
            lRow = Workbooks(strFile).Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
            wbkMs.Activate
            With Workbooks(strFile).Worksheets(1)
                Set searchcell = .Cells.Find(what:="VARIEDAD")
                Set offsetaddr = searchcell.Offset(1, 0)
            End With
            Workbooks(strFile).Worksheets(1).Range(offsetaddr.Address & lRow - 3).Copy
            lRow2 = wbkMs.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
            wbkMs.Range("D" & lRow2 + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            strFile = Dir
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: (1) Which cell(s) are you actually trying to copy? (2) When using `Find` best to check you've found something and specify more parameters (3) Some of those `Withs` look redundant.

Comment: In your copy line `offsetaddr.Address` will return something like B5 and then you are concatenating `lRow - 3` so will get something like B550 if e.g. lrow=53, which I guess is not what you intend.

Comment: I use "find" to look up the column name below which the first data entry is located.

Comment: Since `offsetaddr` is a `Range Variable` you should use `offsetaddr.Resize(lRow - 3).Copy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy Multiple Workbook Column Ranges

- Not tested.
- Before running the code adjust the values in the constants section.
- Opens each workbook in a specified folder and in its first worksheet copies the non-empty column range below the cell containing a specified string to a specified column in another worksheet of an already open workbook.
- The code is in a different (off course open) workbook (concluded due to `Filename.xlsx`).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit
    
Sub looping_through999()
    
    Const wbName As String = "Filename.xlsx"
    Const wsName As String = "Sheetname"
    Const tgtCol As Variant = "D"
    Const FolderPath As String = "H:\folder_path\"
    Const Criteria As String = "VARIEDAD"
    Const FileExtension As String = "*.xls"
   
    Dim Target As Worksheet
    Set Target = Workbooks(wbName).Worksheets(wsName)
    
    Dim src As Range       ' Source Columns Range
    Dim srcFirst As Range  ' Source First Cell Range
    Dim srcLast As Range   ' Source Last Cell Range
    Dim tgt As Range       ' Target Column Range
    Dim FileName As String ' Current Source File Name
    
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & FileExtension)
    Do While FileName <> ""
        With Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FolderPath & FileName).Worksheets(1)
            Set srcFirst = .Cells.Find(What:=Criteria, _
                                       After:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, _
                                                     .Columns.Count), _
                                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                       LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows) _
                                 .Offset(1)
            Set srcLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, srcFirst.Column).End(xlUp)
            Set src = .Range(srcFirst, srcLast)
            Set tgt = Target.Cells(Target.Rows.Count, tgtCol) _
                            .End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(src.Rows.Count)
            tgt.Value = src.Value
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
    
    ' Note that Target is a worksheet and its parent is the workbook.
    ' Save Target Workbook.
    'Target.Parent.Save
    
    MsgBox "Column data transferred.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```